# Hibernate: persistence after change object in detached state

Tags: java, hibernate, persistence

I faced the problem linked with changing persistent object in detached state. Such changes does affect some object in server, but for some reason doesn't affect the object's mapping in DB.

**What I have:**

Two entities that are linked with one-2-many assosiation: Profile->File. I've profile with file list, to which I try to add new files.

**What the problem:**

I firstly clean profile's file list (in II-section) and then I add new files to profile (in III-section). After all, **in DB I have all files, including the files that were removed by profile.getFileList().clear()**;

**Question:**

Why after all I have in DB old files, if I proceed profile.getFileList().clear()?

**My code:**

```
//I. pull the profile from BD
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
Profile existingProfile = (Profile) session.get(Profile.class, profileId);
session.close();

//II. make the copy of profile, out of the session scope, and clear file list of it
String serializedProfile = convertToJson(profile); 
profile = Utils.jsonToObject(serializedProfile , Profile.class);
profile.getFileList(); // not empty!
profile.getFileList().clear();

//III. add new files to profile's file list
Session session1 = sessionFactory.openSession();
session1.beginTransaction();
profiles.getFileList().addAll(additionalFileList);
session1.saveOrUpdate(profile);
session1.getTransaction().commit();
session1.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

Is the II-section in session scope and why would do you call the convertToJson(profile) before clearing the FileList

Comment: no it isn't. I call convertToJson(profile) to proceed clear() operation out of the session scope. Actualy, it is simplified model of my client-server iteraction.